# Change Apache2 ports.conf in order to localhost interface to listen to port 80

Tags: apache2, virtualhost, hosts, ports, virtual-hosts

At the moment I have this config in `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80
```

All works fine, but I want to change it to:

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
```

However after restarting apache, it displays the following error message:

```
[warn] NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80 has no VirtualHosts
```

So I've updated the website VirtualHost file under `/etc/apache2/sites-available/foo.com`:

Original:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
...
</VirtualHost>
```

Updated:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
...
</VirtualHost>
```

But after restarting apache, it shows the default apache2 index.html that is in `/var/www` instead of the project under `/var/www/foo`

This is the only enabled VirtualHost on the server.

Also here is my `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   debian
<publicIP>  <foo.com> <serverhostname>
```

The host OS is Debian 7.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you symlinked the /etc/apache2/sites-available/foo.com to /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-foo.com.

The default apache configuration only reads virtual hosts from the sites-enabled directory and not sites available.

I am guessing that if you go to /etc/apache2/sites-enabled and type `ls -la` you will only see a configuration for default site and not your new site. If this is the case then symlink your foo.com into the sites enabled directory as follows `ln -s ../sites-available/foo.com 001-foo.com`

Comment: Shouldn't be `a2ensite foo` be a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `Listen 80` should have been changed to `Listen 127.0.0.1:80`. All other changes look ok.

Answer (score -2):

- Uninstall apache2 service
- Run update cmd
- Reinstall apache2
- Edit virtual host

This worked for me.